# when go to route (login) after deploy on heroku i get this message Vite manifest not found at: /app/public/build/manifest.json

Tags: laravel-9

Vite manifest not found at: /app/public/build/manifest.json (View: /app/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View: /app/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you've made it but I came across your post, so just wanted to share what I did.

I ran

```
npm i

npm run build
```

in .gitignore, I deleted

```
/public/build
```

then push it to master.

Hope this helps.